# Why can't I see posts or comments by a particular user?

Tags: support

I've noticed several times that I cannot see comments made by a particular user. On my own posts, or on posts made by others. The only reason I know those comments exist are because I see others @-ing them.

The name of the user in question is DilipSarwate. I haven't (knowingly / intentionally) done anything to block them.

As an example, on this post I can see they have asked a question in the comments, but as you can see from the screenshot I can't see the comment:
[Selling house via estate agent vs selling property to developer, UK. Why price difference?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89451/selling-house-via-estate-agent-vs-selling-property-to-developer-uk-why-price-d/89478#89478)

[image: question with comments]

If I search for the user under https://money.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3aDilipSarwate I get a list of posts, none of which I can see the comments on although again I can see other people responding to the comments. (OK, I admit I didn't check every single one, but I picked a random selection and could not see any of them).

What is stopping me seeing the comments (and posts?) by this user? Can I reverse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are sometimes deleted by the users themselves or by a mod. In the case you're referring to, the user deleted their own comment (prompted by your post, I've just cleaned up the comment in reply that doesn't make sense any more either).

In general, I'm not aware of any setting that would give you a different view to any other user. If you had 10K reputation you'd be able to see deleted *answers* (and I think deleted questions if you had a direct link), but only diamond mods can see deleted comments. But in each case they are clearly shaded to indicate that they are deleted.

Looking at your search, I also see plenty of posts with no activity by that user. I'm not sure if the syntax is right, the only documented way to search for a user is by id: https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5760, which produces much fewer results.

If you have other examples, could you check if you get a different view when not logged in?

Comment: OK, thanks for the other way to search for a user - although that only appears to show questions and answers, not comments. Out of interest, how did you find out that "DilipSarwate" is "user 5760"? When I google "@DilipSarwate site:money.stackexchange.com" I get other results where people have addressed comments to that user but in all cases I checked, I can also see the original comment they are responding to.

Comment: I noticed it originally because after our recent discussion about Nationwide mortgages I looked back at a couple of my old posts and saw this one which has the same issue: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/would-extending-my-mortgage-cause-the-terms-to-be-re-negotiated

Comment: It does seem like it must just be that the user deleted those comments, rather than them not being visible to me. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: I confirm the other post also has deleted comments. For the user id, I went to his user page and looked in the URL : https://money.stackexchange.com/users/5760/dilip-sarwate

Comment: How did you find the user page in the first place? I tried to (because I thought it might say "you have blocked this user" or similar) but couldn't find it.

Comment: Top banner -> Users (https://money.stackexchange.com/users) -> type in name

Comment: Huh, I never noticed that! Thank you.